# symfony2 contact form error on rendering to the view page

Tags: symfony

Hey I'm new in this symfony2 framework so i need some helo.

This is a code for contact form and when i'm trying to render the form to the view page it gets some error see the code bellow and the error also.

If any one knows what might be the problem please let me know..

Thanks!

ContactType.php

```
   <?php
// src/Aleksandar/IntelMarketingBundle/Resources/views/ContactType.php
namespace Aleksandar\IntelMarketingBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;


class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'What\'s your name?',
                    'pattern'     => '.{2,}' //minlength
                )
            ))
            ->add('email', 'email', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'So I can get back to you.'
                )
            ))
            ->add('subject', 'text', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => 'The subject of your message.',
                    'pattern'     => '.{3,}' //minlength
                )
            ))
            ->add('message', 'textarea', array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'cols' => 20,
                    'rows' => 2,
                    'placeholder' => 'And your message to me...'
                )
            ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
            'name' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Name should not be blank.')),
                new Length(array('min' => 2))
            ),
            'email' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Email should not be blank.')),
                new Email(array('message' => 'Invalid email address.'))
            ),
            'subject' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Subject should not be blank.')),
                new Length(array('min' => 3))
            ),
            'message' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Message should not be blank.')),
                new Length(array('min' => 5))
            )
        ));

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'constraints' => $collectionConstraint
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contact';
    }
}
?>
```

The controller

```
<?php

namespace Aleksandar\IntelMarketingBundle\Controller;
use Aleksandar\IntelMarketingBundle\Form\Type\ContactType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @Route("contact", _name="contact")
 * @Template()
 */      

         public function contactAction()
    {
    return $this->render('AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle::contact.html.php');

    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType());

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($form->get('subject')->getData())
                ->setFrom($form->get('email')->getData())
                ->setTo('info@intelmarketing.es')
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        'AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle::contact.html.php',
                        array(
                            'ip' => $request->getClientIp(),
                            'name' => $form->get('name')->getData(),
                            'message' => $form->get('message')->getData()
                        )
                    )
                );

            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Your email has been sent! Thanks!');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('contact'));
        }
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );

    }


}
```

the routing

```
aleksandar_intel_marketing_contactpage:
    pattern:  /contact
    defaults: { _controller: AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle:Default:contact }
```

and the contact.html.php which is on the view folder

```
<?php echo $view['form']->form($form) ?>
```

now when i add the the code above in the contact.html.php i got the fallowing

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: form in C:\wamp\www\symfony\src\Aleksandar\IntelMarketingBundle\Resources\views\contact.html.php line 1
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException
```

THE CODE OF MY VIEW

```
<!-- app/Resources/views/contact.html.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><?php echo $view->render('AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle:template:head.html.php') ?></head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="header"><?php echo $view->render('AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle:template:header.html.php') ?></div>
            <div id="leftside"><?php echo $view->render('AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle:template:leftside.html.php') ?></div>
            <div id="rightside"><?php echo $view->render('AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle:template:rightside.html.php') ?>
                <div class="container">



                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                         $(document).ready(function () {
                             if (!$.browser.webkit) {
                                $('.container').jScrollPane();
                                                    }
                                                         });
                    </script>
            <div id="clear"></div>
            </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <?php echo $view->render('AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle:template:footer.html.php') ?>
    </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `form` to this block:

```
$this->renderView('AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle::contact.html.php', array(
    'ip'      => $request->getClientIp(),
    'name'    => $form->get('name')->getData(),
    'message' => $form->get('message')->getData(),
    'form'    => $form->createView(),
));
```

I also noticed that you have

`return $this->render('AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle::contact.html.php');`

As the first line inside your `contactAction` method.  Should probably remove that since your code will not make it past that line and it's just returning the view.

Comment: Well i did than when i remove the first line which you mentioned it gets the blank page now errors just blank page like it creating automatically other contact page..

Comment: Change your Template annotation to this: `@Template("AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle::contact.html.php")`

Comment: now i got this [Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'AleksandarIntelMarketingBundle::contact' at position 49 in method Aleksandar\IntelMarketingBundle\Controller\DefaultController::contactAction().

Comment: sry i forgot to add " on the last

Comment: Double check your annotations to make sure you included the closing parenthesis.

Comment: there you go its added

Comment: Ok, that view is in `app/Resources/views/contact.html.php`, so change your Template annotation to `@Template("::contact.html.php")`

Comment: Sure, you can email it to me. Kenneth.Hannel@gmail.com